# please cut the activity of these cross-site spammers (astroturfers)

Tags: support, user-accounts, spam, astroturfing

Posting at meta solely because I couldn't figure how to make it into a custom flag message (plan to further flag involved posts for mod attention referring to this post).

This [user account](https://stackexchange.com/users/4748992/daniel-walker?tab=accounts) has just posted three similar "questions" at different sites:

- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/266878/any-advice-on-blogging)
- [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/70032/about-blogging)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563201/any-great-blogging-web-sites).

All three have quickly received "answers" from unregistered users linking to the same resource (bloggingtechniques.com).

As far as I can tell, this is spam ([astroturfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing)). Could something be done about this?

Comment: update: posts at UX and AU are deleted; spammer account at AU is deleted too. Guess two upvotes at this question are from moderators at these sites :)

Comment: If you suspect spam, by all means drop a post in [the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). Then all present can have a look, and in serious cases some of the running bots can be updated to include new specific checks for those posts.

Comment: @Bart thanks for reminding! I didn't visit Tavern for quite a long and forgot about this "feature"

Comment: Ux  mod here. I flagged the answer as spam, and then the question too. That way both users get penalised. Then destroy the two users. Best we can do I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spam posts were deleted, spammer accounts at AU and UX were destroyed.

Note to self, next time I see something like this, follow advice given in [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245763/please-cut-the-activity-of-these-cross-site-spammers-astroturfers#comment804234_245763):

> If you suspect spam, by all means drop a post in [the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). Then all present can have a look, and in serious cases some of the running bots can be updated to include new specific checks for those posts.